# Running Macro Using a Negative Timer Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a timer in cell A1 that is populated by external software. Often it will go into negative time values.

I am trying to add a condition to a change event macro so that it runs only when the timer is less than 10:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timer").Range("A1").Value < TimeValue("00:10:00")
```

This works ok when the timer is between 00:10:00 and 00:00:00 but when it goes into negative values the macro stops running.

How do I change the condition so that it continues to run when the time goes negative?

Thanks

Comment: But the negative values are simple errors, or it should be the correct time, but negative? If an error result, you can simply skip `...Range("A1").Value < 0`. If correct but only negative you can try `Abs(TimeValue(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timer").Range("A1").Value))`.

Comment: The macro should not stop if the values goes into negative as the condition will be `TRUE` for negative values as well. Here is a simple way to test it. In Cell `B1` put `8/10/2020  1:22:38 PM` and in `C1` put `8/10/2020  1:24:46 PM`. Finally in Cell `A1` put the formula `=B1-C1`. Now in Immediate window type `?ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timer").Range("A1").Value < TimeValue("00:10:00")`. BTW a quick question. How are you populating `A1`?

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru. The negative value is correct. Your suggestion gives me a runtime error 13 Type Mismatch too

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to a decimal, that should solve the issue:

`CDec(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timer").Range("A1").Value) < CDec(TimeValue("00:10:00"))`

Comment: Thanks jblack. This gives me a runtime error 13 Type Mismatch

Comment: That's probably because `Range("A1").Value` is not always numeric or has an error. What value exactly can be found in `Range("A1").Value` when you get the runtime error? It may be the format in which your program spits out the negative numbers has some issue, maybe a string with spaces, an error value, etc.